# How to add html/js query to gwt app using gwt-rpc?

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, gwt-rpc

We have a web client built with GWT that talks to a server via gwt-rpc. One part of the app will now use html/js to replace the GWT GUI and we want that part to talk to the server but not via gwt-rpc. What ways are there to migrate a gwt-rpc call to something that will work with a none a gwt client? Today we send and receive java collections that contain object graphs like a list of order objects that have them self order detail objects and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is using [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Your data is sent using JSON, which is part of JavaScript so it will always be understood on the client-side. On the server side there shouldn't be any problems finding a suitable library to handle the rest (ha-ha, get it?).

If you're using GWT on the client and server side for now, [resty-gwt](https://resty-gwt.github.io/) and [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) are a popular combo. There was a [talk about it](http://gwtcreate.com/videos/index.html#rpc-jersey-resty-gwt) on the last GWT.create conference, it's a good starting point.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.